# using count and echo to print arrays value

Tags: php

hey am new to php and in my course I have found a code that made me confused.

```html
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$arrlength = count($cars);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
  echo $cars[$x];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

so using `count` to count arrays value and then `echo` to print it in the screen as a number **3** .
the above code printed the arrays values as string I mean like this **Volvo BMW Toyota** . can someone explain this for me ? thank you ♥

Comment: Array count() returns 3 causes it just counts the arrays keys in your array
But once you use for loop in your code you're just breaking array count into x = 1,2 and 3 then using $cars[$x] You're basically re using x = 1,2 and 3 to echo the values found in keys 1,2,3.

Comment: At the end of the code somewhere, add `var_dump($cars);` to see how the array looks, it might make more sense?

Comment: Array count() returns 3 as there are 3 keys in your array But once you use for loop in your code start from 0 as array index start from 0 so it is showing $car[0] (value Volvo), $car[1] (value BMW), $car[2] (value Toyota), when $x become 3 which is not liss than total count loop exits, hope ot helps :)